# Angular Post Request Cors issue

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I got CORS issue when I am trying to make post request to c# web api.
Below is the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api url in different domain' from origin
>   'client url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The same API call with **GET request** is working.

Both sites are deployed with windows authentication enabled.

I am using Angular io, 1.7.** with typescript. Below is how I call the api with post request in typescript.

```
let httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeader = httpHeader.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.post(this.apiUrl, this.bodyObject,
  {
  headers: httpHeader,
  withCredentials:true
}).pipe(map(response => {
  return response;
})).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I first thought that it might be api cors issue and tested with below jquery code and it is working.

```
   <script>

       $.ajax({
            url:apiUrl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                serviceName: "Country"
            },
            xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.info(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        });

  </script>
```

So I think, I have something to do with my angular code. Can you guy highlight me what could be the issue.

Comment: `CORS` issue is when the server denies transferring data to the client, so your angular code is good the problem is with the server side. did you set `config.EnableCors(cors);` in `WebApiConfig` class ?

Comment: for POST, you need to modify your API server, add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * `

Comment: It could be that your request through `ajax` has CORS header added by default(might be dependent on your `jquery` version) and your angular `post` doesn't contain that header.You need to check request headers

Comment: Hi skroid and Umesh, As I explained in it, those .net code are already added in api (server side)and tested with jquery as (client side). Just with that angular typescript (httpClient) in particular, it is not doing the job when it is doing the post request.

Comment: @ThanHtetAung httpHeader = httpHeader.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); httpHeader.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); try this once and check

Comment: Thank @Olegl for your advice, it help me. That angular http post call change into OPTIONS method whereas jquery can simply make the correct POST method. Just different way of cors handling, so I have no choice to change my server side to accept those particular methods and header types coming from angular request. And it solved. :D. Note : cannot use *, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in $.ajax

```
headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
          },
crossDomain: true,
```